# can't get audio to play from python, on raspberry pi

Tags: python

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+

For speaker, I have some ear phones plugged into the 3.5mm audio jack.

If I try

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ omxplayer ./mario1.mp3
Audio codec mp3float channels 2 samplerate 44100 bitspersample 16
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
have a nice day ;)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

That doesn't play the mp3. So maybe omxplayer doesn't send it to the audio jack by default.

If I try

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ omxplayer -o local ./mario1.mp3
Audio codec mp3float channels 2 samplerate 44100 bitspersample 16
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
have a nice day ;)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

That works. So the mp3 is fine and the ear phones are fine. And the audio jack is fine.

But I can't get it to play from python.

**Method 1**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat ./testplayaudio.py
# https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-play-audio-with-the-raspberry-pi

import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/pi/mario1.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python ./testplayaudio.py
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

**Method 2**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat ./testplayaudio2.py
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python

from pygame import mixer  # Load the popular external library

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('/home/pi/mario1.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python ./testplayaudio2.py
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

**Method 3**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat ./testplayaudio3.py
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python

import playsound
playsound.playsound('/home/pi/mario1.mp3', True)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python ./testplayaudio3.py
No handlers could be found for logger "playsound"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testplayaudio3.py", line 4, in <module>
    playsound.playsound('/home/pi/mario1.mp3', True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/playsound.py", line 254, in <lambda>
    playsound = lambda sound, block = True: _playsoundAnotherPython('/usr/bin/python3', sound, block, macOS = False)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/playsound.py", line 229, in _playsoundAnotherPython
    t.join()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/playsound.py", line 216, in join
    super().join(timeout)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

All three of those python methods make no sound!

I'm trying to get the audio to play in Python on my Raspberry Pi.  So, why have those methods not worked and what would?

Comment: @jsotola   I've now added a last paragraph. Is it clear to you now? It says "I'm trying to get the audio to play in Python on my Raspberry Pi. So, why have those methods not worked and what would?"

Comment: Is the default audio output device the HDMI port? Maybe you need to change it - in the desktop I think you can right click the audio icon and select audio jack.

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino thanks.. Now method 1 works. Methods 2 and 3 don't work and still give the same output

Comment: Surely method 2 is exiting before it has a chance to play the file?

Comment: @CoderMike thanks.. adding `input()` at the end to stop the program exiting, ensures that method 2 works

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino You can post that as an answer and i'll accept it.  As that's probably the raspberry pi issue.  Method 2 is more of a python related issue. Method 3 might be a python related issue.

Comment: related re method 3. - https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/100  not yet answered

Answer (score 0):

The default audio device on the Raspberry Pi is usually the HDMI output, so you have to change it to the audio jack. In the desktop, you can right-click the audio icon and select the audio jack as the default audio output device.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the HDMI interface, you can turn it off in raspi-config and all audio defaults to the 3.5 jack. I am running a python script at boot using import vlc to play some mp3's as PBX hold music. The script runs as root and audio will always output on HDMI no matter if Aux is set as default. Disabling HDMI helped me solved the issue.